# Function return, only returns 1 value on for loop

Tags: python

I am writing a code that would return 2 random numbers from a list of numbers into an empty list outside of the function deal_card(). But when printed, it only return 1 value. I tried with different indentation and still it only return 1 value. Thanks in advance.

```
import random
def deal_card():
  for card in range (2):
    cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    card_length = len(cards)
    pick = random.randint(0, card_length-1)
  return cards[pick]
      
   
user_cards = []
user_cards.append(deal_card())
print(user_cards)
```

Comment: `return cards[pick` will only return one element

Comment: Each time through the loop, you overwrite `pick` so you only have one value to return. You'd need to either build a list and return it, or you could use `random.sample()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
def deal_card():
    picked_card=[]
    cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    card_length = len(cards)
    for card in range (2):
       pick_index=randint(0, card_length-1)
       picked_card.append(cards[pick_index])
    return picked_card

user_cards =deal_card()
print(user_cards)
```

Here, we have stored all the cards in a list named cards. We have created an empty list picked_card. We are using for loop in range(2) because we want to pick two cards. Every time the loop runs we pick a random integer between 0 and total number of cards-1 and store it as pick_index. we add a card from cards to the picked_cards list using the pick_index. After the picking process is done by for loop, the picked_card list is return by the function which can be printed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to return any number of values you desire, including 2.

```
def deal_card(n):
  import random
  pick = []
  for card in range(n):
    cards = [11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    card_length = len(cards)
    pick.append(cards[random.randint(0, card_length-1)])
  return pick
      
   
user_cards = []
user_cards.extend(deal_card(2))
print(user_cards)
```